# Retrieve Drive Letter Of File With Batch File

Tags: batch-file

So depending on the port/computer I plug my flash drive into it is recognized and a different drive letter, as you all know. I need the code to find my flashdrive name and report back to me the letter of the drive. This is what I have, so you can look at it and try to figur out what I am doing wrong.

```
set DriveLabel=JERRYG225

for %%a in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
pause
 for /f "tokens=6 delims= " %%i in ('vol %%a: ^|find "drive"') do (
  pause
  echo %%i | find /i "%DriveLabel%" > nul
 )
)
```

Comment: What *is* wrong for you about your present code?

Answer (score 1):

There's a better way to find the assigned drive letters and volume names.

With given available hard disk partitions `C:` with volume name `DriveC`, `D:` with volume name `DataDrive`, and a USB disk drive on `E:` with volume name `BackupDisk`,

```
wmic logicaldisk get caption^, volumename
```

produces (at a command prompt):

```
Caption VolumeName
C:      DriveC
D:      DataDrive
E:      BackupDisk
```

Using it in a batch file and removing the column names:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1* delims= " %%x in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^, volumename') do (
  echo %%x %%y
)
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to match `%%y` with `DRIVELABEL` and save the matching `%%x` if found. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a similar function for my daily tasks that doesn't rely on `WNIC`, which requires administrative rights. I used the serial number of the USB drive since labels are unreliable.

```
:GetDriveLetter %SerialNumber% DriveLetter
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "Letters=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    for /L %%I in (0,1,25) do (
        set Drive=!Letters:~%%I,1!:
        if exist !Drive! (
            dir !Drive!|findstr /L "%~1" >NUL
            if not ERRORLEVEL 1 (
                set Result=!Drive!
                goto :GetDriveLetterRet
            )
        )
    )
    :GetDriveLetterRet
    endlocal &set "%2=%Result%" &goto :EOF
```

To get the drive letter of your USB drive you do a call like this:

```
call GetDriveLetter ABCD-1234 Drive
if defined Drive (
    pushd !Drive! 2>NUL && (
        REM do things here
    )
) else echo Can't find USB drive^^! & pause >NUL
```

**Edit:** To get the serial number of your USB drive just do a `DIR` or a `VOL` command on that drive.